# CSS Horizontal Menu is showing list bullets

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I am using this code:

```css
#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}

#menu li {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

#menu li a {

    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left : 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    
    font-family: "Tahoma";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #8f8b20;
    text-decoration : none;
}

#menu li a:hover {

    background-color: #dad68c;
    
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left : 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#menu li a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #dad68c;
    
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left : 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Foods</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>            
 <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

</ul>
```

For a Horizontal CSS menu which is working fine on jsFiddle but when i am using it in my site.. it is giving me bullets of the list, see the image below....

[image]

**HOW TO GET RID OF THESE BULLETS**

<kbd>**F1**</kbd> <kbd>**F1**</kbd>

<kbd>**Help !!!**</kbd>

<kbd>**Any Key**</kbd>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify this style:

```
#menu li {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Like  this: (You are missing `list-style` property)

```
#menu li {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style:none; // this should remove the bullets
}
```

**More Info:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: That is the simple truth :), jsFiddle uses a [reset-css](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) I believe, so that's why you don't see any bullets there! This reset removes all the default-browser settings.

Comment: @Justus Romijn: True i should have mentioned that in my answer but thanks for adding that :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried list-style?

```
ul {
      list-style: none;
      ...
      ...
}
```

Comment: That will apply to all `ul` elements :)

Comment: Sure, it's just an example of how you'd use list-style. :) He can reduce the scope to a specific id or class like you did in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS code is missing a rule for `ul` setting `list-style: none`

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the default `<li>` style by adding `list-style: none;` to `#menu`. Adding that to `#menu li` will have the same effect, but it takes 3 extra characters. :)

The reason jsFiddle looks fine is that the CSS they're applying to the whole page is dealing with it for you.

Read more about [list-style-type](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style-type.asp), and the short-hand [list-style](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style.asp) (used above).